# How many of the words contain the text string "mat" somewhere in the word?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This problem consists of three problems.

**(i) How many different words can be made by rearrangement of the letters in the word "matematik"?**

*my answer*

$$\frac{n!}{k_m! \cdot k_a! \cdot k_t! \cdot} = \frac{9!}{2!\cdot2!\cdot2!}= \frac{9!}{8} = 9 \cdot 7!$$

**(ii) How many of these words starts and ends with "t"?**

I just removed the two "t" from the word "matematik", so now I have "maemaik".

My calculations are as follows

$$\frac{n!}{k_m! \cdot k_a!} = \frac{7!}{2! \cdot 2!} = \frac{7!}{4} $$

**(iii) How many of the words contain the text string "mat" somewhere in the word?**

How should I understand this question?

Understanding 1: How many of the words found in (i) contain one "mat"?

Understanding 2: How many of the words found in (i) contained at least one "mat"?

If assume understanding 2 is the right way to read, my answer is (per intuition)

$$7!-\frac{5!}{2!}$$

I'm not sure how to explain my calculation with words. (Probably because my understanding is not sufficent).

PS 1 The word "matematik" is danish. It means "mathematics".

PS 2 The problem has been translated from Danish into English. The original problem had som ambiguity which has been eliminated.

PS 3 Also, "matematik" is a word. But "amtematik" is not a word. Our professor should have used "text string" in stead of $word$ in the formulation of the problems.

Comment: I highly tend towards understanding 2. For understanding 1, they'd have to mentioned 'once', 'exactly once', or something in that spirit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should be understood as "*at least one* $mat$" – $mat$ only has to appear *somewhere* and there is no restriction on the count of this substring.

Your answer for this part is correct and may be justified by the inclusion/exclusion principle. $7!$ is the number of permutations of letters when one of the $mat$s is considered a single "letter". We double-count the strings with two $mat$s here, so we subtract $\frac{5!}2$, the number of permutations when both $mat$s are considered "letters".

Answer (score 1):

I would go by your second guess, that is having at least one "mat" in the string.

For a solution assume the letters "mat" being one entity and calculate the permutations with this entity and the rest of the letters. Luckily "mat" has the only repeating letters so the permutation will be easy.

Hope this helped